# .NET framework 4.5 downwards compatibility

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

Can a windows application built using .NET framework 4.5 be run on a machine using .NET framework 4 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can if you do not leverage anything specific to .NET 4.5 and if the application's .config file does not [demand .NET 4.5 as a runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4kkd0k5.aspx).

Comment: I am really confused. Hans Passant mentioned in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351798/why-a-machine-with-net-4-installed-on-it-cannot-run-an-exe-that-targeted-net-4) that this is not possible. The question also sites MSDN in even milder case (.NET 4.5.1 app on .NET 4.5.2): _'An executable that targets the .NET Framework 4.5.1 will be blocked from running on a computer that only has the .NET Framework 4.5 installed, and the user will be prompted to install the .NET Framework 4.5.1. In addition, .NET Framework 4.5.1 assemblies should not be called from a .NET Framework 4.5 app.'_

Comment: @BorislavIvanov: The question here is specific to targeting 4.5(.0) and running on a machine with 4.0.  4.5.1 and 4.5.2 behave differently, as outlined in the question you reference due to the internal changes outlined there. .NET 4.5.1 had not been released when this question was asked.