# Unknown Build Error 'Method get_Command' in type does not have an implemntation

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

Full error.

```
 error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Method 'get_Command' in type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RepeatButton' from assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Line 6 Position 14.'
```

I am attempting to upgrade a vb.net project from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.7.1
The above error is being thrown in all the xaml files in the project with different controls e.g RepeatButton, MenuItem. There are no error lines showing when i open the file.

I have also upgraded another branch with that points at the same PresentationFramework.dll from .Net4.7.1 which built fine.

Comment: Save your project, Clear Solution and Rebuild Solution. If problem still exists close VS and open again

Comment: RepeatButton.Command returns an ICommand.  It is one of the notorious types that got moved from one assembly to another in .NET45.  You are surely building with the wrong reference assemblies, the kind of problem described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353220/17034).

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, unfortunately that did not work

Comment: @HansPassant how would i go about making sure the project is looking at right 4.7.1 assemblies even when the dll path is correct and not 4.0

Comment: "even when the dll path is correct".  You have good evidence that it is not correct.  We can't tell how you verified this, nor is it something that is easy to get wrong.  Consider repairing it by opening the project in VS, removing all references from the References node and adding them back.  Beware of wonky custom build systems, "MC1000" is pretty wonky, if you use one then be sure to reformat its disk.

Comment: @HansPassant before when i removed and added the presentationframework.dll it still didnt work. This time i went through and removed all .net dlls and added them again. It solved the issue. If you want to post as an actual answer il accept it

Comment: you are allways on old version ; from assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0

Comment: @GCamel no, file version is not the .net version. It is still version 4.0.0.0 and working

Comment: do you have an app.config file with the supportedRuntime ?

Comment: Did you managed to resolve this issue? I am having the same problem..

Comment: @DaniCode yes. I went removed all .net dlls from project and cleaned then added them again

Comment: It was an empty windows, I've deleted it :) I saw that if I add a new one, it is different because of the different .Net Framework.